# Why i am getting this error: variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am getting this error  warning  Assignments to the 'height' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

this is my code

what happen?

```
const MyComponent = ({
  height,})=>{

 useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        if (height < 10) {
          height = 10
        }
     const newValue = calculateValue(height, width)
    }
    if(isNotValidate){
       getData()
    }
}
```

by the error i am using useEffect but the error following apparing

Comment: `height` appears to be a destructured props value. Props are to be treated as immutable. The error is saying that each render that the `height` prop is reset to the passed value. What are you trying to do with this `height` value?

Comment: @DrewReese how can i solve?

Comment: Well, other than trying *exactly* what the error suggests, I think the answer to your question revolves around what you are trying to do/use `height` for.

Comment: @DrewReese i just want to set new value if the current value is less to 10, and then calculateValue

Comment: `const newValue = calculateValue(height < 10 ? 10 : height, width)` this should do

Comment: `const newValue = calculateValue(Math.max(10, height), width)` works too

Comment: structure of your code needs heavy improvement. try/catch, async/await, don't mutate props, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, state and props are to be considered and treated as immutable. When you set `height = 10` this mutates the props object. The error is saying that each render that the `height` prop is reset to the passed value.

> I just want to set new value if the current value is less to 10, and
> then calculateValue

You can use the maximum of `height` or the value 10.

```
const newValue = calculateValue(Math.max(height, 10), width)
```